# How to add a delay without locking the current process (a la Thread.Sleep())?

Tags: c#, timer

I am relatively new to programming, so I apologize in advance if any of my explanations are difficult to make sense of!

I have been working on a console application, and I am attempting to implement a console animation that runs through once before allowing the program to proceed.  At the moment, I have attempted to implement this using the following:

```
bool check = true;

while(check == true)
{
    spin.animation();
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    check = false;
}
```

However, this doesn't work, as the Thread.Sleep call freezes the thread, thus causing the animation to be completely static!

I have attempted to research various alternate ways to tackle this problem, but I am currently quite confused as to how to proceed.  I have seen System.Timers.Timer mentioned a few times, but I do not seem to have this as an option in my library.  System.Threading.Timer is another frequently cited solution on related issues, but as far as I can understand, this doesn't seem to be entirely suitable for what I'm trying to achieve.  Async/await framework is another option that I've seen mentioned.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction by suggesting an appropriate way of solving this issue.  I'd be even more appreciative if you could provide a bit of information as to how I would use it in the context of my problem.

Thanks!

UPDATE: As requested, the code behind spin.animation()...

```
public class ConsoleAnimation
{
    private int currentAnimationFrame;

    public ConsoleAnimation()
    {
        SpinnerAnimationFrames = new[]
            {
                "........",
                "*.......",
                "**......",
                "***.....",
                "****....",
                "*****...",
                "******..",
                "*******.",
                "********",
                "*******.",
                "******..",
                "*****...",
                "****....",
                "***.....",
                "**......",
                "*.......",
            };
    }

    public string[] SpinnerAnimationFrames { get; set; }

    public void animation()
    {
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        var originalX = Console.CursorLeft;
        var originalY = Console.CursorTop;

        Console.Write(SpinnerAnimationFrames[currentAnimationFrame]);

        currentAnimationFrame++;
        if(currentAnimationFrame == SpinnerAnimationFrames.Length)
        {
            currentAnimationFrame = 0;
        }

        Console.SetCursorPosition(originalX, originalY);
    }
}
```

'spin' is declared in the Program class with 'ConsoleAnimation spin = new ConsoleAnimation();'

Comment: Can you show your code for spin.animation() please

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` will block the current thread, `Thread.Delay` will delay without blocking the current thread.

Comment: @Ben I've added an update with the code for spin.animation();

Comment: @NicolasZawada I've tried adding Thread.Delay, but this didn't seem to exist :S Did you mean System.Threading.Task.Delay? In which case, I've tried this too but it seems to immediately trigger 'check = false' without first running the animation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your code, I see that you are trying to print '*' in the pattern you set.

But, you are modifying your flag to **false on the first loop iteration**, which means you will **always see '*'** as your console log. Code suggestion from me is

1. **remove the Thread.Sleep(500)**
2. instead of assigning "false" to the "check" variable statically, get the value as a method return value from and check if you completed one iteration

   ```
   bool check = true;

   while(check == true)
   {
       check = spin.animation();        
   }
   ```

   and **animation()** function like below

   ```
   public bool animation()
       {
           Console.CursorVisible = false;
           var originalX = Console.CursorLeft;
           var originalY = Console.CursorTop;

       Console.Write(SpinnerAnimationFrames[currentAnimationFrame]);

       currentAnimationFrame++;
       if(currentAnimationFrame == SpinnerAnimationFrames.Length)
       {
           currentAnimationFrame = 0;
       }

       Console.SetCursorPosition(originalX, originalY);

       return currentAnimationFrame!=0?true:false;
   }
   ```

Comment: I had a go at implementing this solution, in practice it seems to immediately change bool check to false.  The program seems to skip right over the while loop without pausing or running the animation.  Not sure why, as it looks like it should work :S

Comment: in that case, you add the Thread.Sleep(500) back inside the while loop. Another way is to induce a delay by adding a loop that does nothing inside (last choice for me as this will hold the current thread for doing nothing except waiting).

Comment: Huh?  "Without locking thread with Sleep"? "remove Thread.Sleep".  "Add the Thread.Sleep(500) back"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer (System.Timers.Timer)` class to toggle your check:

In your constructor initialize the timer:

```
    Timer _timer = new Timer(500);
    _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
    _timer.Start();
    while (check == true)
    {
      spin.animation();
    }

    private static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var timer = sender as Timer;
        check = false;
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: This would call the spin animation over and over.. spin.animation() would need to be before the while loop.

Comment: The problem I've encountered here is that when I add 'using System.Timers', I get 'The type or namespace name 'Timers' does not exist in the namespace 'System'... Is this only available with certain versions, or why could this be?

Comment: @Ben thats what OP wants to do, to call animation method again and again for certain times.

Comment: In which case a simple datetime check might be easier than using timers, but otherwise your timer implementation sounds good

Comment: @Ben, can you post how datetime check be implemented to achieve this?

Comment: @jamessct, do you have system.dll reference in your project or you accidently removed it?

Comment: Nitin I have posted the DateTime solution

Comment: @Nitin I haven't made any changes to the project files, but someone else set up the project environment for me so maybe some change was made.... Is there a specific line I could search for to confirm whether or not something has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5); // Spin for atleast 5 seconds
DateTime end = now + t;

while (DateTime.Now < end)
{
    spin.animation();
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is working for me!  Many thanks for the help!